# how to send multidimension array from titanium to php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, titanium-alloy

```
var send = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({

        onerror : function(e) {

            Ti.API.debug(e.error);

            alert('There was an error during the connection');  
        },      
});

send.open('POST', 'abc.php');   

var data = Ti.App.Properties.getList('cart'); 

//data containing js array object: 

i.e:[{"key":"5736","quantity":"1","product_name":"Fruit Raita","price":"75.00"},{"key":"11454","quantity":"2","product_name":"Veg. Harabhara Kabab","price":"90.00"}]

send.send({             

      products:JSON.stringify(data),        
});
```

//now how to retrive this array in php?

i have tried following things:

1)`json_decode($_POST['products']);`

2)`var_dump`

3)`json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['products']));`

how could i use this array in php??

Comment: what is the result of var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: can't able to print array in php! bcoz in titanium they are giving error! is there any way to print received array in php??

Comment: did you check this : https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/69051/post-json-string-into-a-php-page

Comment: yea! i am returning product_name from php file by using $a=json_decode($_POST['products']) &                               $a[0]['product_name'],but it is returning null